# Spring Data entity column property is always null when reading from the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

On an existing DB table I've added a column and in the JPA entity I've added a property as well.
I've initialized the new db column with default values.

```sql
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD NEW_COLUMN VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR);
UPDATE MYTABLE SET NEW_COLUMN = 'AAA';
```

```java
@Column(name = "NEW_COLUMN", nullable = false)
private String newColumn;
 
@Query(value = "select * from mytable ", nativeQuery = true)
```

The query returns all the rows in the table, but the field newColumn is always null, the other fields are populated correctly.
When I do the same query on the command line, the values for the column are there.

What could be the reason that JPA returns null values for that new column?

Comment: check may be
getColumn in Entity-Class is return null (explicitly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why JPA return null for that new column.
In SQL developer, I initialized the new DB column with value "AAA", but I didn't commit after the SQL finished the update.  After I did a commit in SQL Developer, the JPA query returned the value "AAA"